# xcode static library public/private/project header files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, header-files

So, I have an iOS app project with a static library as subproject. As found multiple times here on SO, you should set the visibility of the library header files to public/private/project, depending on who should be able to use them.

Based on that, I created one class with a header file that exposes functionality to the app project (or whoever is going to use this library). Naturally, this header file imports a number of headers from other classes inside the library project. As these other header files do not provide functionality that should be exposed to the library's users, i would like to set these to "project", making them invisible to the rest of the world.

However, when i set header files to "project" they don't get copied into any of the private or public header folders. This results in a `'ProjectHeader.h' file not found` error when using `#import "ProjectHeader.h"` in the `PublicLibraryClassHeader.h` when compiling the app project that uses the library.

So the question is: How can I set header files to "project" in a library project and stil use them from within that library project? Am I misunderstanding the concept of public/private/project header files in static libraries?

Comment: The easies way is to convert your static library into framework. Framework is a static library in a specific container, that does all magic for you. Btw, this words about public headers are related to frameworks, not to static libraries.

Comment: Well that explains a lot! thanks for the tip.

Comment: @ErikVerboom I have same problem . I want to visible only header that will be used by client of my framework . But when i add then in project header they are not more visible in public header file . Please suggest me how do you solve this problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easies way is to convert your static library into framework. Framework is a static library in a specific container, that does all magic for you. Btw, this words about public headers are related to frameworks, not to static libraries.

Comment: Nope, frameworks are fancy shared libraries aka dynamic, not static.